# Can we save file from html page in android device using javaScript

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

I am prompting window on desktop to save file on local device by using following code

```
if (finalResult == '') {
    alert("Invalid data");
    return;
}
var result2 = nameObject.personalInfo[0].Name;
var result3 = nameObject.personalInfo[0].Number;
var fileName = result2 + result3;
var uri = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + escape(finalResult);
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.href = uri;
link.style = "visibility:hidden";
link.download = fileName + ".csv";
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
document.body.removeChild(link);
location.reload();
```

By this user can get CSV into excel. Will same code work for android devices?
If not then please suggest me alternatives.
Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11338522

Comment: @Sreekanthss using JavaScript will it work. Actually I don't have device for testing

Comment: hope so, try that all the best